# Images from URL source vs. Local files in an Express server

Tags: node.js, express, thumbnails

I have a (very) large library of high resolution images stored off site that I access with URLs.  These are artworks that need to keep their full size for client side viewing.  My server wastes no bandwidth simply listing the URLs to plug into `<img src="">` elements, but the webpage takes a long time to load because, even though they are put into thumbnail sized containers, it has to load the full size first before resizing for the container.

So my question is: would it be better to have these files stored locally? Will that also slow down the website load time?  We are talking about multiple gigabytes of image data, so it seems like a mobile user could blow through their entire month's data just visiting the site. I have tried npm modules like `sharp` and `image-thumbnail` to generate thumbnails, but they do not seem to work for URL sourced images.

I see a few potential workarounds, but none seem ideal:

1. Store the files locally (several hundred files), and me physically updating the files as they need to change (adding or removing images), meaning I will probably have hard code a new image every time they want to change something.
2. Keep the offsite storage, but create a whole new storage with just thumbnail sized images for displaying on the page (more work for my client who will be managing the content post-production).
3. Somehow take my list of URLs and resample the images into lower resolution and post them back to storage using some kind of REST API.
4. Erase the storage completely, but create an input field on the site for my client to upload them one by one, generating a thumbnail upon upload (this will take a long time as I mentioned there are many images).

Can anybody share some insight on best practices for this situation?